# Parsing string including currency code?

Tags: c#

I know there are many question similar to this one explaining how to parse a string with a currency symbol. Here I would like to do the same but with currency ISO-4217 code (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217).

```
decimal.Parse("45,000.00 USD", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint)
decimal.Parse("45.00 USD")
decimal.Parse("USD 45.00")
decimal.Parse("USD45.00")
decimal.Parse("45.00USD")
decimal.Parse("45.00 RUP")
decimal.Parse("IND 45.00")
decimal.Parse("45.00 EUR")
decimal.Parse("INR 45.00")
```

I was thinking about a solution with regular expression but maybe there are more direct solution or something already exist in .NET lib. I don't know.

Comment: Is this just for the one code and all codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NumberFormatInfo.

See the example i have written below.

```
var nmfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nmfi.NegativeSign = "-";
nmfi.CurrencySymbol = "USD";
nmfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
nmfi.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";

var result1 = decimal.Parse("USD45.00", NumberStyles.Currency, nmfi);
var result2 = decimal.Parse("45.00USD", NumberStyles.Currency, nmfi);
var result3 = decimal.Parse("45.00 USD", NumberStyles.Currency, nmfi);
```

Comment: This example only work for a specific symbol. Here USD. 1. "USD" is not a symbol. using it as a CurrencySymbol is more a workaround than a solution. 2. It this working with many different currency code. I'm not checking the currency exist or not right now.

Comment: @ngeksyo The person you're responding to *is* the OP, so it's a bit strange telling them they've misunderstood the question. That said, the original question *was* only asking for USD examples.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment I have no better solution than mine

```
public static decimal Parse(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("s is null");
    var match = Regex.Match(s, "[A-Z]{3}");
    if (!match.Success)
        throw new FormatException("s is not in the correct format. Currency code is not found.");
    s = s.Replace(match.Value, string.Empty); // I don't like this line
    decimal value = decimal.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Currency);
    return value;
}
```

In my code I use a Money Object. Money is composed by a decimal value and a 3 character currency code.

```
public static Money Parse(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("s is null");
    var match = Regex.Match(s, "[A-Z]{3}");
    if (!match.Success)
        throw new FormatException("s is not in the correct format. Currency code is not found.");
    s = s.Replace(match.Value, string.Empty); // I don't like this line
    decimal value = decimal.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Currency);
    return new Money(value, (CurrencyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(CurrencyCode), match.Value));
}
```

Comment: This solution is great, if you want to strip out the currency symbol and just extract the numbers that you want.

Comment: @B412, I just started converting https://github.com/richardschneider/money-works (javascript) into C#.  If you would like to collaborate send email to makaretu at gmail dot com

Comment: I think the best robots are able to read your email even like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is to bundle the decimal number with it's format so that it is easy for you to know what currency the value is for. I have created `IsoDecimal` helper `struct` to help with such thing.

```
void Main()
{
    var arr = new string[]
    {
        "45,000.00 USD" ,
        "45.00 USD"     ,
        "USD 45.00"     ,
        "USD45.00"      ,
        "45.00USD"      ,
        "45.00 RUP"     ,
        "IND 45.00"     ,
        "45.00 EUR"     ,
        "INR 45.00"    
    };

   foreach (var num in arr)
   {
        Console.WriteLine(new IsoDecimal(num).ToString());
   }
}
```

The `struct` is here.

```
public struct IsoDecimal
{
    private NumberFormatInfo numberFormat { get; set; }
    private decimal value { get; set; }

    public IsoDecimal(string strValue)
    {
        string strNumber = Regex.Match(strValue, @"[\d.\-,]+").Value;
        string code = Regex.Match(strValue, @"[A-Z]+").Value;

        numberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo();
        numberFormat.NegativeSign = "-";
        numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
        numberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";
        numberFormat.CurrencySymbol = code;

        value = Decimal.Parse(strNumber);
    }

    public static implicit operator decimal(IsoDecimal isoDecimal)
    {
        return isoDecimal.value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString("C");
    }

    public string ToString(string format)
    {
        return value.ToString(format, numberFormat);
    }
}
```

The `struct` allows you to assign its value to a `decimal` variable at will in case you need it, and it overrides `Object.ToString` to that it is seamless to integrate and work with.

Answer (score -1):

You could use regex

```
Decimal.Parse(Regex.Match("USD 45.00", @"(\d+(\.\d+)?)").Value);
```

Comment: This is not correct. Your regex don't include the decimal.