# How to use ISO-4217 for currency validation in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to add Currency Validation to my API Req Payload,I was using Regular Regex to do currency validation like

```
public class PaymentValidator : AbstractValidator<Payment>
{
    private static readonly Regex _regex = new("^[a-zA-Z]{1,3}$");

    public PaymentValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(request => request.Amount).GreaterThan(0);
        RuleFor(request => request.Country).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(request => request.Currency).NotEmpty().Matches(_regex);
    }
}
```

However, I recently came across a couple of links

- https://www.iso.org/iso-4217-currency-codes.html
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.regioninfo.isocurrencysymbol?view=net-5.0#examples

This looks to me much more promising & for production I want to replace all my curreny validation Regex using it.

How can I use `iso-4217` for this?

Thanks!

Comment: ISO 4217 is a standard - you can't "use it" - you need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Does it need to be like this：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41866761/parsing-string-including-currency-code

Answer (score 2):

This is how I addressed this my requirement

This NuGet came to the rescue.

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/ISO.4217.CurrencyCodes/

  ```
  public PaymentValidator()
  {
    RuleFor(request => request.Currency).NotEmpty()
   .Must(receivingCurrency => ISO._4217.CurrencyCodesResolver.Codes
   .Any(c => c.Code == receivingCurrency));
  }
  ```

:)